# Compare row-wise two matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices to compare in Matlab, `A` of dimension `MxN` and `C` of dimension `MxN`.
I want to get an index  equal to `1` if there is `i` such that `A(i,:)` differs from `C(i,:)` and `0` otherwise.

For example

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
C=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 10 11 12];
index=1;
```

I want the fastest code possible.

Also, can you provide a second version of the code, if different from earlier, for the case in which

(1) `A` contains only zeros and ones and `C=zeros(M,N)`, and

(2) `A` contains only zeros and ones and `C=ones(M,N)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isequal` to perform an element-wise equality and then negate it with `~` to see if there were any cases where `A` and `C` differed.

```
index = ~isequal(A, C)
```

If `A` and `C` are floating point numbers, then you'll want to not use *exact* equality checks and use something like

```
index = ~any(abs(A(:) - C(:)) < eps);
```

As for the second part of your question, you'll have to add an additional conditional

```
index = ~isequal(A, C) || ...
        (all(ismember(A(:), [0 1])) && (all(C(:) == 0) || all(C(:) == 1)));
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do I have to add other conditions for the second part of my question?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Suppose `A=[1 1 1; 0 1 0; 1 0 1]` and `C=[0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]`. Then `index = ~isequal(A, C)` gives me 1 as desired. What are the other conditions `(all(ismember(A(:), [0 1])) && (all(C(:) == 0) || all(C(:) == 1)))` doing?

Comment: @user3285148 but if A and C ARE both all zeros you would expect a 1 as well

Comment: If `A=zeros(3,3)` and `C=zeros(3,3)`, by doing `index=~isequal(A,C)` I get zero as desired.

Comment: @user3285148 But if `A` and `C` are all zeros, then this criteria is satisfied: "A contains only zeros and ones and C=zeros(M,N)"